# Divide numbers in same column in python

Tags: python

In Python, I have a dataframe and want to divide the numbers in same column.(such as divide 6 by 9 in column c)

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df2
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

Comment: Do you want to divide numbers from the top to the bottom? Do you want to add a total row at the bottom? Also, what solutions have you tried already?

Comment: I want to show the answer in a new column for example 3/6=0.5 show in row 1, 6/9=0.67 in row 2, display in new column

Comment: I think you should elaborate a little bit more your question. Try to include what you tried, what searched etc